# Getting access token from Azure AD from React frontend

Tags: reactjs, azure, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have a React SPA and ASP.NET web API, both registered applications on Azure.

I have authentication setup so the user logs in and authenticates through the tenant for the front-end application. But now I need to get a bearer token for the API application in the front-end to pass along with the API calls.

I figured the workflow would:

Call https://login.microsoftonline.com/TEANTID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize -> get authorization code
-> Call  https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANTID/oauth2/v2.0/token with previous auth code, which will return a bearer token to use in the API call, but both the top requests will always return

"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)."

My understanding is I cannot change that, so what must I be doing wrong here? I can see Swagger calling those endpoints just fine as well as Postman but I cannot replicate.

I followed a lot of the examples and guides but they only seem to be for getting an access token for the front-end application. I have that, but now I need to also authenticate for the API afterwards.

This is my msalConfig being used to authenicate into the front-end

```
export const msalConfig = {
auth: {
    clientId: "FRONT-END-APP-ID",
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANTID",
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000"
},
cache: {
    cacheLocation: "sessionStorage", // This configures where your cache will be stored
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
}
```

Index.tsx

```
   const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
      <App />
    </MsalProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Are you using `@azure/msal-react`?

Comment: yes i am, for users to log into the app.

Comment: You would use the same to get the access token for your API as well. Only thing you will change is the `scopes` which should now be something like `['api://927ffbbf-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-033d9c015580/.default']`

Comment: I had a feeling, but how would use the same to get a second token for the API? create a second msalConfig and use the API client ID/scopes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created two Azure AD Applications and exposed an API in `ASP.NET` web API App:

[image]

I agree with *Gaurav Mantri*, In the **React SPA (Frontend) Application** added the API permission like below:

[image]

I generated **auth-code** by using below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=RedirectUri
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://ClientID/.default
&code_challenge=XXXXX
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

[image]

**I generated access token by using below parameters:**

[image]

[image]

Modify the **`msalConfig`** file of your React Frontend like below:

```js
auth: { 
authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID",
clientId: "ClientID",
postLogoutRedirectUri: RedirectURI
redirectUri: RedirectURI
validateAuthority: true,
navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
},
cache:
{ cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
},
},
{
scopes: ['api://clientid/.default']
},
LoginType.Redirect
```

***If still the issue persists***, add the CORS policy in your React Application by setting it by allowing all the origin. `cors.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());`

**Reference:**

[React.JS + MSAL with ASP.NET Core to use Azure AD by Mark Deanil Vicente](https://dnilvincent.com/blog/posts/reactjs-msal-with-aspnetcore-to-use-azure-ad-part3)